Is there an algorithm that produces a uniform distribution over the set of trajectories with maximum reward sum?
I am not an expert in reinforcement learning. I am applying it to my field of study.
I am training a model such that given a state, it predicts the probability of taking an action for every action possible. As such the model can be described as M: S -> P where P is the set of all probability vectors over A, the discrete action space. S is the set of all possible discrete states.
The model takes actions stochastically to create a finite trajectory (I do not choose the action with maximum probability, instead, I sample trajectories). Multiple trajectories have the same reward (summed over the state-action units in the trajectory).
Define G to be the set of trajectories with maximum reward sum.
If I train such a model using any mainstream algorithm (Q-learning, actor-critic, etc.) the model will learn, loosely speaking, to maximize the probability of a trajectory from G. It will not learn a uniform distribution over the set G. Instead, probability will concentrate on a specific trajectory. This is not an exploration problem as far as I know, since even if the model explores every possible trajectory, probability will still concentrate on one trajectory. And it is not inherently a problem in reinforcement learning, it is specific to my use case.
I would very much appreciate any references that tackle this problem. I am searching for an algorithm that produces a uniform distribution over the set G and a negligible probability for all other trajectories.

Are you attempting to build a model which finds all (or many) optimal policies in an environment?

@foreverska yes, in a sense. All these optimal policies should be summarized by one model that, in a sense, samples uniformly from one of them.

Q-learning will indeed learn a trajectory, as they are all equivalent, and usually the resulting policy of a Q-learning algorithm is a greedy policy, which selects:
$$
a = argmax_a Q(s,a)
$$
so, no matter what you do, the final policy in your case has to be deterministic.
In the actor critic scenario, this is not obvious. Indeed, if two actions $a_0$ and $a_1$ lead to trajectories with the same expected return, when you update the actor using:
$$
\nabla J(\theta) \approx \mathbb{E}[G_t \nabla_\theta \ln \pi(a|s)]
$$
you can clearly see that both the actions will be reinforced equally
However, you have to consider that the overall objective of RL is to maximise:
$$
\mathbb{E}[\sum \gamma^tr_t]
$$
In order to that to happen, going back to the previous scenario, any linear combination between the policy that always selects $a_0$ and the one that always selects $a_1$, will be an optimal policy, as the all lead to the same solution (solution meant as expected sum of rewards)
A very simple example of this, is by considering the trivial case where you have 2 bandits (think about slot machines) that give the same expected return $C$: your policy return will be $V = p(a_0)C + p(a_1)C$, clearly, any combination of the two probability lead to the same value (obviously having $p(a_0)C > 0, p(a_1) > 0, p(a_0) + p(a_1) = 1$)
However, luckily for you, there is an easy fix if you want the policy that not only maximizes the expected sum of rewards, but it's also as stochastic as possible, that is to introduce an entropy bonus
$$
\nabla J(\theta) \approx \mathbb{E}[G_t \nabla_\theta \ln \pi(a|s)] + \mathcal{H}(\pi)
$$
And this solution, will select the policy $\pi$ that also maximises the entropy, thus making it as stochastic as possible, thus distributing equally the probability mass across actions that lead to trajectories with the same expected return

Thank you. Your answer led me to this research paper that addresses my problem perfectly. For future readers: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.05905.pdf

@‍Alberto: Your last paragraph is wrong. Adding an entropy term destroys the optimality and the policy you get would generally not optimize expected return. Whether this is a good heuristic for the specific use-case or not is a totally separate question, but you cannot claim optimality. CC @moeasal

I think that the entropy bonus needs to be weighted carefully, and potentially down over time. It may be useful initially to discover different equivalent trajectories, but it will also cause a preference towards action distributions that are not optimal when the entropy bonus is close to scale of the rest of the objective. Also, are you sure adding this bonus to the gradient works? I think that's equivalent to maximising the squared entropy measure - probably ok, but a little odd

The entropy measure is probably some log sum over the probability distribution anyway, so this weirdly ends up looking a bit like L2 regularisation

@NeilSlater yes it's the sum of log terms, though I'm not sure how you can end up with an L2 regularization...

I mean it has the "rough feel" of L2 weight regularisation, except due to positive direction is about  largest distribution (as opposed to smallest individual numbers), and also of course it is not weights being impacted but output probabilities. And like regularisation, it's a balance between two potentially opposing objectives

@NeilSlater i mean i hardly see appearing any squared term, but you can see it as something like adding $-||p(a)-1/N||^2$, thus giving a bonus the closer you are to to uniform ($N$ being the number of actions you can perform)

@user21820 i agree with you that you are adding a small bias, however you can pretty clearly interpret it as a Lagrangian of the constrained problem which maximizes the entropy s.t. the policy value is the maximum

@NeilSlater sorry, only now i saw your first comment… yes it works and it has been done many times, for example in the paper of SAC (though sure, it needs a scalar carefully chosen)

The very fact that you need a constant weight on the bonus term already tells you that it cannot be correct. The closer the weight to zero, the closer to optimality. You can't have both optimality and preference for stochastic trajectories! Sure, we may want some trade-off, but you need to be clear about that.

@user21820 not sure how you can be so sure about it: assume we find the optimal policy without entropy with value $V^$, then problem $\max \mathcal{H}(\pi) s.t. V(\pi) = V^$ is for sure well defined, AND feasible (though maybe intractable) AND the solution is that the OP is looking for, but the "the fact that you need a constant weight on the bonus term already tells you that it cannot be correct" goes 100% against the concept of Lagrangian (Lagrange multipliers) in constrained optimization, so I'll suggest you to give it a look :)

@user21820 after looking at that, I then suggest you take a look at the paper of PPO, where they use the Lagrange multiplier form of the loss when talking about the KL version of the objective, and show that with a dual descent mechanism,e you can be very close (note that the "constant" work in this comment section has been used only by you, I've never said that it needs a fixed value)

I know the Lagrange multiplier technique, which is not at all the same as what you are doing. Optimizing entropy after optimizing the return value of course can be done, but you cannot do both simultaneously by just arbitrarily adding two terms. You are misunderstanding my use of the word "constant"; what I said was exactly in line with what @NeilSlater said, namely that you need to weight the two terms and gradually adjust the weights. You also agreed that you need 'carefully chosen' weights, and "very close" ≢ "optimal". My point is just that as written in your post it cannot be optimal.

@user21820 https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.01290.pdf proof B.1... i would say that is pretty close...

I am not strictly convinced that Q-learning should necessarily learn a singular optimal path.  Given infinite exploration, Q-learning should estimate the reward of all actions.  In a state where two actions have the same reward the tie should be broken randomly (giving all equal paths the same probability of being followed).  The remaining actions would have zero probability of being followed given a perfectly deterministic maximizing agent.
In practice we do not explore infinitely or our estimators do not learn infinitely.  This might account for the perception that it finds a singular near optimal path.  Often the problem space is too large and our estimators too opaque to inspect what has actually been learned.  I would challenge to experiment with tabular Q-learning on a multi-armed bandit where more than one arm has equivalent rewards.
So I guess my answer would be that the issue is unlikely to be with the learning method but with the learning hyper-parameters (learning rate, epsilon annealing rate, etc).

thank you so much for the insight. would you say the same about actor-critic? and does this problem have an official name so that i can find literature discussing it?
